# Doubts about NodeJS Module Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, node-modules

I'm trying to code my very first NodeJS module, but I'm having trouble grasping some concepts.

Here's the code that I currently have (a *genexer* counter/generator):

```
"use strict";

var ret = require('ret');

module.exports = function (regex) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(regex) === '[object RegExp]') {
        regex = regex.source;
    }

    else if (typeof regex !== 'string') {
        regex = String(regex);
    }

    try {
        var tokens = ret(regex);
    }

    catch (exception) {
        return false;
    }

    return {
        charset: '',
        reference: [],
        count: function (token) {
            var result = 0;

            if ((token.type === ret.types.ROOT) || (token.type === ret.types.GROUP)) {
                if (token.hasOwnProperty('stack') === true) {
                    result = 1;

                    token.stack.forEach(function (node) {
                        result *= count(node);
                    });
                }

                else if (token.hasOwnProperty('options') === true) {
                    var options = [];

                    token.options.forEach(function (stack, i) {
                        options[i] = 1;

                        stack.forEach(function (node) {
                            options[i] *= count(node);
                        });
                    });

                    options.forEach(function (option) {
                        result += option;
                    });
                }

                if ((token.type === ret.types.GROUP) && (token.remember === true)) {
                    reference.push(token);
                }
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.POSITION) {
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.SET) {
                token.set.forEach(function (node) {
                    if (token.not === true) {
                        if ((node.type === ret.types.CHAR) && (node.value === 10)) {
                        }
                    }

                    result += count(node);
                });
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.RANGE) {
                result = (token.to - token.from + 1);
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.REPETITION) {
                if (isFinite(token.max) !== true) {
                    return Infinity;
                }

                token.value = count(token.value);

                for (var i = token.min; i <= token.max; ++i) {
                    result += Math.pow(token.value, i);
                }
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.REFERENCE) {
                if (reference.hasOwnProperty(token.value - 1) === true) {
                    result = 1;
                }
            }

            else if (token.type === ret.types.CHAR) {
                result = 1;
            }

            return result;
        }(tokens),
        generate: function () {
            return false;
        },
    };
};
```

Questions:

1. am I calling `count` correctly on my first iteration? `count: function (token) {}(tokens)`?
2. how can I recursively call the `count` method? I get a "ReferenceError: count is not defined"
3. is this the correct (or best-practice) approach of defining a small module with several methods?

Forgive me for not posting 3 different questions, but I'm not very familiar with all the terminology yet.

Comment: 1) That works but the proper notation is `(function() {})()` I believe 2) use `this.count(/*args*/)` 3) I would define the module outside of the return statement so you can reference it's methods in other methods more cleanly (ie `mymodule.count()` instead of `this.count()` )

Comment: Explicit comparisons to `true` and `false` are unnecessary and potentially problematic.  If a function returns a boolean result, just use the result of the function call directly without a comparison.

Comment: @megawac: I did try `this.count()` but I got the same error. I will try to do what you suggested in #3, maybe that fixes #2 as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Pointy: I've always looked at explicit comparisons as a good practice, I think even JSLint complains if you don't use them. Why do you say they are potentially problematic?

Comment: @AlixAxel Yeah, when I wrote that I didn't realize `count` was a closure function

Comment: @AlixAxel they're problematic because a given API may or may not return an explicit boolean value even if it's written with the intention of being used as a predicate.  It's not idiomatic in JavaScript to code like that, though it may be in some other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The convention for immediately invoked closures is `count: (function(args) {return function() {}})(args)` but your way will also work in all environments.
2. You can't because count is a closure unfortunately - see 3.
3. If you want to use methods on your module inside your module I would declare the module outside of the return statement. If you want a good example of this see [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-9)/<s>lodash</s> source code.

So you can define your module using a declaration like the skeleton below

```
module.exports = function (regex) {
    //...
    var count = function(tokens) {
        //...
        return function() {
           //...
           var ret *= count(node);


           return ret;
        }
    }
    var mymod = {
        count: count(tokens)
        //...
    };
    //...
    return mymod;

};
```

Comment: Thanks, those examples were very helpful! One more question if I may: `mymod.count` will return the resulting number of possible regex matches. I would like to do the same for the generate method, however I don't want it to run when the module is required, just when the actual method is called. What approach do you suggest to achieve this and always pass `tokens` as the argument to those methods? Let me know if I'm not being clear.

Comment: For instance, `mymod('hello?').count() == 2` and `mymod('hello?').generate() == ['hell', 'hello']`. Is this possible?

Comment: I'll get back to you after I take a look at the `ret` module

Comment: Your answer got me in the right track, `mymod.count()` didn't work but I managed to solve both problems in one go. Thank you for the help. =)

Comment: I was going to mention that `mymod.count` wasn't going to be a function but good stuff :)

Comment: Yeah, but even if you remove the argument call you can't still call `mymod.count` recursively (don't ask me why, but it doesn't work).

Comment: Oh its because when you pass the next node you're passing it to the closure of `mymod.count` (with tokens). You would need to defined `count` outside and define the closure with tokens seperately